# Can't raise the event on client/server app

Tags: c#, .net, events, client-server, .net-remoting

I'm implementing a multi player game with .NET Remoting. The client connect to the server, and i can play the game. There is no problem with the connection etc. however; i subscribe the event in the client side, and when the event is fired nothing happens.

The server side network implementation is like that:

```
SetupTcpChannel();
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(GamePlay),
"MyGame.soap", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
RemotingConfiguration.CustomErrorsEnabled(false);
```

The client side:

```
SetupTcpChannel();
var myGame = (IGamePlay)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IGamePlay), "tcp://localhost:13101/MyGame.soap");

private void SetupTcpChannel()
{
    // Creating a custom formatter for a TcpChannel sink chain.
    BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider server_provider = new         BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
    server_provider.TypeFilterLevel = Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;

    BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider client_provider = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();

    // Creating the IDictionary to instantiate the channel with custom sinkprovider
    IDictionary properties = new Hashtable();

    properties["port"] = "0"; //let the system choose the portnumber to prevent double portnumbers with multiple clients

    // Pass the properties for the port setting and the server provider in the server chain argument. (Client remains null here.)
    TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(properties, client_provider, server_provider);
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
}
```

The delegate and event in the IGamePlay interface :

```
public delegate void getMessageDel();
event getMessageDel event_message;
```

The function in the GamePlay class:

```
public void function() {
    if (event_game_started != null)
        event_game_started();
}
```

Subscribe the event in the client side:

```
myGame.event_game_is_over += new gameIsOverDel(myGame_event_game_is_over);
void myGame_event_game_is_over()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Game is over!");
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to consider switch to WCF, say named pipe, it will save a lot your time and nerves. It's the official replacement of .NET Remoting.

Comment: it is an assignment for a course of mine, so i am supposed to do it with .NET Remoting.

Comment: For the client to be callable, it should be MarshalByRef, and in an assembly accessible by the server. Are these conditions met? More info [here](http://aviadezra.blogspot.com.ar/2008/06/code-snippets-remoting-client-server_19.html) about how to wire up the whole process with events and using a shared assembly between both counterparts.

Comment: It is MarshalByRef, I've solved the problem, i should have defined 

void myGame_event_game_is_over() as public. Since the default is private.

Comment: As an FYI, when you don't specify an access modifier the default access modifier is "protected", not "private".